# Opening txt file from visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2012, system.io.file

I have, it seems, a simple problem. I need to open a "txt" file using visual studio. As usually I use standard code:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open);
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs);
```

No need in another code. If the txt file was created using

`FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create);`

and then I change FileMode to Open, visual studio sees the file and I can work with it.

But, if file the txt I created without using visual studio (for example right click of mouse and then create file), I cannot use

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open);
```

because compiler says that the file is not found. Whats wrong?

Comment: The file path is wrong then. Where do you create the path?

Comment: File path can not be wrong. I put txt file in directory, where c#  file is situated.And even tried to put all file path in new FileStream(fullpathandname,FileMode.Open)